# Best approach for handling view-related properties in model (fetched from a remote service)

Tags: angular

Assuming I have an interface, for example:

```
export interface Alert {
    alertId: string,
    alertMessage: string,
    timestamp: Date,
    alertType: number
}
```

That I display in a component, for example;

`app.component.ts`:

```
alerts : Alert[];

ngOnInit(){
     this.alerts = this.getAlertsFromRemoteService();
}

getAlertsFromRemoteService() : Alert[] {
     //http get request...
}

updateAlertInRemoteService(alert : Alert) {
     //http post request...
}
```

`app.component.html`:

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let alert in alerts">
         <td>
              <button (click)="updateAlertInRemoteService(alert)">
         </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Now I want to change the view while `updateAlertInRemoteService` is running (Change the class of the `tr` to `disabled`, for example). What is the best approach for doing that?

Yes, I can of course change the `Alert` interface to have something like `submitting: boolean`, But that way I'm "interfering" with the integrity of the model...

What would you do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the "submitting" logic in a separate array that is initialised when the data is loaded, and toggled when the data is being updated.

```js
alerts : Alert[];
submitting: boolean[];

ngOnInit() {
  this.service.getAlerts().subscribe(alerts => {
    this.submitting = alerts.map(() => false);
    this.alerts = alerts;
  });
}

updateAlertInRemoteService(index: number) {
  this.submitting[index] = true;
  const alert = this.alerts[index];

  // http post request...
  this.service.update(alert).subscribe(() => {
    this.submitting[index] = false;
  });
}
```

Then your HTML can deal with indexes and bind to the submitting array.

```html
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let alert of alerts; index as i" 
      [class.disabled]="submitting[i]">
    <td>
      <button (click)="updateAlertInRemoteService(i)">
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Alternatively you could keep the signature of `updateAlertInRemoteService` as you currently have it, and find the index for the submitted `alert`.

#### Using a view model

Another option here would be to use a view model.

```js
export interface AlertViewModel {
  alert: Alert;
  submitting: boolean;
}
```

You would create an array of these in your component and manage the submitting state in the view model. This has the benefit of keeping your original model clean, and keeps your view-concerns out of your domain models.

Comment: Would you personally prefer this approach over changing `Alert`?

Comment: That's entering the realms of opinion. I would certainly want to keep my domain model pure. I would create a view model interface if I want to store some view-specific concerns in a model.

Comment: I've added an example of a view model that I might create